# angular form validation - ng-valid to start

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular-auto-validate and am having some state management issues. I have a multipart form where some fields are required (name/email address) and the user is able to go "back" to change answers. Basically, I have a partial for every stage in the form which is working well, with one exception. The continue button is disabled if the field is invalid. I tried simply using the $valid identifier, but when the partial loads, each field begins with `ng-valid` so I can either use $touched or $pristine. Problem is, when the user goes back, the value that has binded to a data source is valid, but the field isn't touched so the continue button doesn't activate. Sample code (this is generated code after I've hit the "back" button):

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Your First Name" ng-focus="inputFocused()" ng-pattern-err-type="" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" class="ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength">
```

and the button:

```
<a href="/#/setup" class="button round" ng-class="{'disabled': !signupForm.name.$valid || !signupForm.name.$touched }" ng-click="completeStep()">Continue</a>
```

How can I either disable the default `ng-valid` or identify a condition where the value is being populated by the controller?

Comment: Is it maybe `$dirty` that you want to use? $touched is just for focus I think

Comment: according to the docs, that means the form has been interacted with. I don't think that will work when the page is a new load and the form is prepopulated...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you pre populate the data it becomes dirty. If you set the scope in your controller then that scope variable will be dirty

Comment: dirty doesn't apply (at least in my app) when it is prepopulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use ng-dirty/pristine.  You can manually set the condition of the form as the user navigates.
When you populate your form data you can do something like:

```
if($scope.myForm.data) {
  $scope.myForm.$setDirty
}
```

Your button:

```
<a href="/#/setup" class="button round" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine" ng-click="completeStep()">Continue</a>
```

Comment: I didn't end up using this solution, but rather chose to base it on $invalid instead, but I think this solution would be another way to deal...